# Contingency Table from ANOVA?

Tags: anova

I am needing clarification on something that I thought I read was possible and is stuck in my head needing answered as I am not following how to do it or I just missing a key concept.  I am not a statistics guy by nature and something obvious may be not clicking so any assistance is appreciated.

Is it possible to construct a 2x2 contingency table (TP/FP/TN/FN) from a ANOVA table that contains the Sum of Squares from the Regression (SSR), Sum of Squares for the Error (SSE), Total Sum of Squares (SST) with a given sample size of X and a regression equation?

If so, please provide a step-by-step example of the steps to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer, no, at least to my knowledge.

I think you are confused about a few things here including what a contingency table is.  A contingency table is nothing more than a table that displays frequency distributions.  When you refer to TP,FP,TN,&FN you are referring to a hat you describe is a special contingency table known as a **confusion matrix**.  A confusion matrix is (in binary situations) a 2x2 matrix containing the predicted group memberships.  For example:

```
   A  B      A   B
A  5  2    A TP  FP
B  3  8    B FN  TN
```

This is typically used to evaluate the performance of a predictive algorithm.  In this case there are 5 true positives, 2 false positives, 3 false negatives, and 8 true negatives.  You can ultimately use this table to derive many other statistics (e.g. Accuracy, Kappa, Sensitivity, etc).

The generic contingency table is simply a representation of the distribution of groups in a population.  For example (copying from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table)):

```
         Right-handed  Left-handed  Total
Males    43            9            52
Females  44            4            48
Total    87            13           100
```

Now, this is, more-or-less, raw data that you can use to test a hypothesis.  Assuming the data fits some assumptions, some tests include chi-squared, fisher's, and the G-test among others.

This is different from ANOVA (which in this case would be two-way).  ANOVA uses some **quantitative value** as opposed to just counts.  Your output is intended to be used to interpret how the quantitative variable is impacted by the factor.

Comment: Thanks this helps, the origin of the question was I encountered a problem set once that based on my understanding of how to get the answer at the time you first needed to construct a contingency table to derive the other statistics like you mentioned above. So you are probably correct that I really mean specifically a "Confusion Matrix".